# Where to put the DESC clause in this query without having an error?

Tags: sql, database

I am new to sql and having issues with the following query:

```
SELECT AVG(people.weight),
             (people.playerid),
       (people.namefirst),
       (people.namelast),
       (batting.teamid),
       (teams.teamid),
       (teams.name)
 FROM people
 JOIN batting
 ON people.playerid = batting.playerid
 JOIN teams
 ON teams.teamid = batting.teamid
 GROUP BY (people.playerid),
       (people.namefirst),
       (people.namelast),
       (batting.teamid),
       (teams.teamid),
       (teams.name)
 LIMIT 30;
```

Where am I supposed to enter the DESC clause in the query without having an error ? What am I doing wrong ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't need al l the `()`s. Those should be for grouping things or function calls. e.g. `(this OR that)`, or `count()` , `sum()`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

DESC can be one of two things:

DESC is an [optional part of the ORDER BY clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_desc.asp) and goes [after the GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) but before the LIMIT. It controls whether the sort happens in ascending or descending order.

DESC can [describe the table structure](https://way2tutorial.com/sql/sql-desc-table.php) (I think this is specific to MySQL though), but this seems to have nothing to do with your select query.

Comment: Thanks ! It still gives me an error though :                                                                   SELECT AVG(people.weight),
    (people.playerid),
       (people.namefirst),
       (people.namelast),
       (batting.teamid),
       (teams.teamid),
       (teams.name)
 FROM people
 JOIN batting
 ON people.playerid = batting.playerid
 JOIN teams
 ON teams.teamid = batting.teamid
 GROUP BY (people.playerid),
       (people.namefirst),
       (people.namelast),
       (batting.teamid),
       (teams.teamid),
       (teams.name),
 ORDER BY 1 DESC,
 LIMIT 30;

Comment: @SimoneGhilotti No comma between DESC and LIMIT. You can use this site to check the syntax: https://www.eversql.com/sql-syntax-check-validator/  Or any other similar one you find when you google "sql syntax check"

Comment: @SimoneGhilotti Also, whats the point of the ORDER BY 1 DESC? I don't think that will actually do anything. At most, reverse the order of results.